# codeIgniter update data based on search

Tags: php, codeigniter

Based on search a form wiill be displayed with data based on search . I want to update this data with a button on the search result page. the update doesn't work and when I use var dump null values are returned

please help me out
view:

```
    <h3> Allowances: </h3>
<div class='panel panel-info'>
    <div class='panel panel-heading'></div>
<?php foreach ($allowance as $data): ?>
 <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_label( $data->name); ?>
        <?php echo form_input(['class' => 'form-control', 'name' => 'amount','value' => $data->amount]); ?>
  

      <?php echo form_hidden(['class' => 'form-control', 'name' => 'emp','value' => $data->emp_id]); ?>
<?php echo form_hidden(['class' => 'form-control', 'name' => 'comp','value' => $data->comp_id]); ?>

    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</div>

<a href='<?php echo base_url('payroll/update') ?>' class="btn btn-primary" type='submit'> Update</a>

    COntroller
     public function update(){
        $emp_id = $this->input->get('emp');
        $comp_id =$this->input->get('comp');
        
        
        $d = [
            'amount' =>$this->input->post('amount')
        ];
        $this->payroll_model->update($d,$emp_id,$comp_id);
        var_dump($d);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Successfully updated');
    }
model 

    public function update($d,$emp_id,$comp_id){
//    $array = array('emp_id'=>$emp_id,'comp_id' =>$comp_id);
//    $this->db->where($array);
    $this->db->where('emp_id',$emp_id);
    $this->db->where('comp_id',$comp_id);
    $this->db->update('emp_sal',$d);
    return true;
enter code here
enter code here
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting null values returned is that the line below redirects to the link in href instead of posting user's inputs

```
<a href='<?php echo base_url('payroll/update') ?>' class="btn btn-primary" type='submit'> Update</a>
```

To overcome this issue, use a form tag with action attribute that has the value of

```
base_url('payroll/update')
```

Such as the following

```
<?php echo form_open(base_url('payroll/update'), array('method'=>'post')) ; ?>
```

Replace the a tags you are using with the following input that submits user values instead of just redirecting with null values

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" type='submit'> Update</input>
```

Comment: It doesnt get updated,Im getting null values from $emp_id and $comp_id (although the values are in the form), also only the data from the last form is captured

Comment: You need to specify the method in your form tag, make it POST. I have edited the answer.